# Access To Acronis True Image 2016 Files

Tags: permissions, acronis-trueimage

I have just made a copy of my old computer’s hard drive with Acronis True Image and put the file onto my new HP Envy which I can mount the partitions within the image file using Acronis True Image on the new computer.

Unfortunately I am refused access to the mounted folders as I don’t have permissions.

I have tried to grant myself full access but the buttons don’t come alive for me to do this in the permissions area.

Any idea how to grant permission when no choice is given – do I have to work backwards to move forwards?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on the Acronis website, you have to restore the files before you can change permissions.

.
[image]

[Source of Information](https://kb.acronis.com/content/1549)

Answer (score -1):

This is why Acronis should bring back the writable image mounting.  They dropped that feature in the 2015 version, bad idea in my opinion.  I was just searching this because I need to access files in a image that blocks me because windows can't write new permissions to the partition.  That's why the "access denied" message appears.

If you restore any system files, as is the case if you restore a user's folder, windows will not let you delete them.

Only solution to avoid having junk files stuck on your system is to use a spare drive and restore the partition to it so you can access the files.

Comment: This is more of a comment then an actual answer